# Issue with Datetime from database and Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-datetime

I'm trying to generate some basic chart data, but I cannot, yet anyways.
Whenever I retrieve datetime values from Django models, it gives me this output:

```
[print(i) for i in UserAnalyticsMeta.objects.all().values('created_at')[:3]]
```

```
{'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 15, 22, 43, 23, 88381, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
{'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 15, 22, 48, 43, 944993, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
{'created_at': datetime.datetime(2022, 8, 15, 22, 48, 49, 95255, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
```

Which translates to:

```
2022-08-15 22:43:23.088381+00:00
2022-08-15 22:48:43.944993+00:00
2022-08-15 22:48:49.095255+00:00
```

However, when I try to print out the date, this is the output I get:

```
[print(i) for i in UserAnalyticsMeta.objects.all().values('created_at__date')[:3]]
```

```
{'created_at__date': None}
{'created_at__date': None}
{'created_at__date': None}
```

While I expect:

```
2022-08-15
2022-08-15
2022-08-15
```

What I've also noticed is that an old function I used also doesn't work anymore, and I feel like it has something to do with this.

```
        select_data = {"date_created": """strftime('%%m/%%d/%%Y', created_at)"""}
        qs = self.extra(select=select_data).values('date_created').annotate(models.Sum("page_visits"))
        return qs
```

Now gives me the error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/app_name/model_name/
(1305, 'FUNCTION app_name.strftime does not exist')
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

#### Edit

I think this is going wrong at the database level, time functions do not work properly anymore. These queries:

```
SELECT DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`extra_analytics_useranalyticsmeta`.`created_at`, 'UTC', 'Europe/Amsterdam')) AS `date_created` FROM `extra_analytics_useranalyticsmeta` LIMIT 3
```

```
SELECT DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`extra_analytics_useranalyticsmeta`.`created_at`, 'UTC', 'Europe/Amsterdam')) FROM `extra_analytics_useranalyticsmeta` LIMIT 3
```

###### These queries get generated by:

```
UserAnalyticsMeta.objects.all().annotate(date_created=TruncDate('created_at')).values('date_created')[:3].query
```

```
UserAnalyticsMeta.objects.all().values('created_at__date')[:3].query
```

return None everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like Django is getting in the way.

```
SELECT DATE(created_at)
    FROM tablename
    WHERE ...;
```

If that gives you what you need, then issue it as a raw command and ignore the rest of the hassle.

Comment: Yes, this worked, it also allowed me to solve the issue. `USE_TZ=False` and it works without changing my queries. Know if there are any downsides to `USE_TZ=False`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you get datetime objects when querying Database you can simply use the datetime objects date function to get the required date.

```
[print(i.date()) for i in UserAnalyticsMeta.objects.all().values('created_at')[:3]]
```

If you want to truncate the time at the query level, then you can use TruncDate function provided by Django

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

items = UserAnalyticsMeta.objects.annotate(
    str_created_at=TruncDate('created_at')
)
```

Sample is shown in the below image[image]

You can see how `custom_date` field is created using `created_at` field that only contains date. You can use this approach according to your requirements.

Comment: The code I posted was an example. I need to work with whole querysets, not instances, and this still wouldn't solve the underlying issue at hand. Thanks for thinking with me though.

Comment: @nigel239 I did not understand that you wanted that at query level. I have updated my answer for getting required result from the ORM query itself. Please have a look at the solution again. 

I have also updated a screenshot for your reference. In the screenshot you can see how I have created a field using created_at with only date in it.

Comment: Hey! I tried it. The following function still returns none on `created_at`  `self.values(date_created=TruncDate('created_at')).annotate(models.Sum("page_visits"))`

Comment: @nigel239 If you see my answer, you need to pass `date_created=Truncdate('created_at')` inside the annotate. As per your comment, you have passed that to values. Which doesn't seem correct.

Comment: `print( UserAnalyticsMeta.objects.all().annotate(date_created=TruncDate('created_at')).values('date_created')[:3])` still returns none, passing it to values or annotate should work either way. :p
`<QuerySet [{'date_created': None}, {'date_created': None}, {'date_created': None}]>`, the query it generates might help? `SELECT DATE(CONVERT_TZ(`extra_analytics_useranalyticsmeta`.`created_at`, 'UTC', 'Europe/Amsterdam')) AS `date_created` FROM `extra_analytics_useranalyticsmeta`